# Binary Search Tree DELETE survey

Tags: ds.data-structures, combinatorics

In helping out @bapi-chatterjee on a [BST question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/20533/height-of-randomly-built-binary-search-tree-by-insert-and-delete) , when it came to teasing out the combinatorics of BST_DELETE(i) I ran into a wall where even under the conservative assumption that the parent tree remains intact, with $k$ children you still have any of the $k!$ insertion sequences to rebuild the children into a new subtree since any legal BST among the children will work.

Is there a survey article on BST deletion algorithms? Most articles simply talk about the [standard textbook BST delete algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Deletion).

Comment: I don't think there's a survey, but check out the Ralf Hinze paper "A fresh look at binary search trees" from 2002. Google will fix you up with a copy.

Comment: Thanks. Hinze's paper also references  Anderson's 1991 paper 'A note on searching in a binary search tree', http://user.it.uu.se/~arnea/ps/searchproc.pdf